# Magento 2: Automatically cancel pending orders older than 10 minutes

Tags: magento2, orders

How to do automatically cancel payment_pending orders in Magento 2.

Older than 10 minutes + status is `Payment_pending`.

This is my code

```
<?php

   namespace Arnavcancleorder\Cancleorder\Cron;

   use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

   class CancelPendingOrders

   {

protected $logger;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 */

public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
 * Execute the cron
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function execute()
{
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $orders = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
               ->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending_payment');
               ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', array('lt' =>  new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('".now()."', INTERVAL -'10' HOUR)"))) ;



              foreach ($orders as $order) {

              $order->cancel()->save();

               }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must execute the cron every minute and check if the last update of the orders were 10 min ago.
For this, you have to create the next files:

> Vendor/Namespace/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="vendor_namespace_cancel_order_pending" instance="Vendor\Namespace\Cron\CancelOrderPending" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Namespace/Cron/CancelOrderPending.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

/**
 * Class CancelOrderPending
 */
class CancelOrderPending
{

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterGroup
     */
    private $filterGroup;

    /**
     * @var OrderManagementInterface
     */
    private $orderManagement;

    /**
     * CancelOrderPending constructor.
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param FilterGroup $filterGroup
     * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        FilterGroup $filterGroup,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository       = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder         = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroup           = $filterGroup;
        $this->orderManagement       = $orderManagement;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $today          = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $to             = strtotime('-10 min', strtotime($today));
        $to             = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $to);

        $filterGroupDate      = $this->filterGroup;
        $filterGroupStatus    = clone($filterGroupDate);

        $filterDate      = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('updated_at')
            ->setConditionType('to')
            ->setValue($to)
            ->create();
        $filterStatus    = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue('pending_payment')
            ->create();

        $filterGroupDate->setFilters([$filterDate]);
        $filterGroupStatus->setFilters([$filterStatus]);

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups(
            [$filterGroupDate, $filterGroupStatus]
        );
        $searchResults  = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria->create());

        /** @var Order $order */
        foreach ($searchResults->getItems() as $order) {
            $this->orderManagement->cancel($order->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create [a cronjob](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html) for this requirement.

That cronjob will run 20mins interval  `<schedule>*/20 * * * *</schedule>`

And at job class `Magento/SampleMinimal/Cron/Test.php`, You have to create order collection and status  `Payment_pending`.

Comment: Thanks for replay Amit Bera ,,,,,
Iam new to magento 2 could you please help if its possible how to do in observer 
for cron Job i have compelted